# How to route IP net to interface using netplan

Tags: networking, development, netplan

The VLAN of eth0 holds 2 IP nets, from the machine with IP
10.64.0.101/27 (eth0@machine-1) I used to connect to the openVPN server at
10.0.0.41/27 (eth0@machine-2) with the IP range 192.168.0.0/24.

The following sniplet in the /etc/network/interfaces:

```
post-up /sbin/route add -net 10.0.0.32/27 dev eth0
post-up /sbin/route add -net 192.168.0.0/24 gw 10.0.0.41
```

worked fine. Of course machine-2 with 10.0.0.41 also had 
    post-up /sbin/route add -net 10.64.0.96/27 dev eth0
in its /e/n/i and ip forwarding enabled.

How to translate it into netplan?

My first shot was

```
   - to: 10.0.0.32/27
     via: 10.64.0.101
     on-link: true
   - to: 192.168.0.0/24
     via: 10.0.0.41
```

Any ideas?

Kind Regards
Maniac

PS: growing the nets to /9 is not an option...

PPS: Yes, anycasts will be visible on both IP nets.

Comment: Your gateway is different between your ifupdown route and your netplan route (10.0.0.41 vs. 10.64.0.41).  Is this a typo in your post?

Comment: @slangasek: yep, fixed, THX!

Answer (score 0):

Heres the example.

I tryed to just comment but it wont let me.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens3:
      addresses:
       - 192.168.3.30/24
      dhcp4: no
      routes:
       - to: 192.168.3.0/24
         via: 192.168.3.1
         table: 101
      routing-policy:
       - from: 192.168.3.0/24
         table: 101
    ens5:
      addresses:
       - 192.168.5.24/24
      dhcp4: no
      gateway4: 192.168.5.1
      routes:
       - to: 192.168.5.0/24
         via: 192.168.5.1
         table: 102
      routing-policy:
        - from: 192.168.5.0/24
          table: 102
```

Read more here : https://netplan.io/examples#source-routing

Comment: Hi, I think you are talking about 2 interfaces on one machine, this does not match my reqest exactly.

Comment: This configuration does not make sense. Why would you communicate with local subnet via router ? This setup does not require source routing. Just configure both interfaces without any routers and everything will work fine.